# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. (Firestore Web)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Environment: development w/ NextJS

I have been developing with Firebase/Firestore under very lenient Firestore security rules andall of my functionality worked fine.

I have defined new Firestore rules shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Internal user data & stripe subscription management
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.userId == userId;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.userId == userId;
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.userId == userId;
      }
      match /payments/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.userId == userId;
      }
    }

    // Stripe products (subscription plans)
    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }

    // Allow signed in users to post fedback surveys
    match /BetaFeedbackSurvey/{survey} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /CoreCompanyInfo/{company}/{info} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match/fiscalYearEndDates/{company} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /PrimerandDebrief/{article} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using this function to fetch the user data from /Users/{userId}.

```
import { firestore } from "@/lib/firebase"
import { type UserData } from "@/lib/validators/user"
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

export async function getUserData(uid: string): Promise<UserData | null> {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(firestore, "Users", uid)
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      return docSnap.data() as UserData
    } else {
      console.error("No such document!")
      return null
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error retrieving user data: ", err)
    return null
  }
}
```

And I'm using a provider to make this globally available throughout the app:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { getUserData } from "@/functions/firebase/getUserData"
import { auth } from "@/lib/firebase"
import { userDataState } from "@/state/user"
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil"

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const UserDataProviderWrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [, setUserData] = useRecoilState(userDataState)

  let uid: string
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    uid = auth.currentUser.uid

    let userData = null
    const setUser = async () => {
      userData = await getUserData(uid)
      setUserData(userData)
    }

    void setUser()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        // User is signed out, clear the userData
        setUserData(null)
      }
    })

    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [setUserData])

  return <>{children}</>
}

export default UserDataProviderWrapper
```

With this current setup, I am getting the error:

```
Error retrieving user data:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
console.error @ client.js:2
window.console.error @ setup-hydration-warning.js:18
getUserData @ getUserData.ts:20
await in getUserData (async)
setUser @ UserDataProviderWrapper.tsx:28
UserDataProviderWrapper @ UserDataProviderWrapper.tsx:31
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19590
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21596
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27421
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26552
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26461
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26429
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25733
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

I have validated that currentUser exists.

I'm very new to web dev, NextJS, and Firebase so any information at all is much appreciated.

I have found a few similar questions where the user was not logged in. This is being called from inside my app and I have logged the user to make sure this isn't the case.

I also successfully ran this validation in firestore rules playground.

Maybe there is an issue with the request itself? I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this though.

Answer (score 0):

It is `request.auth.uid`, not `request.auth.userid`.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request